# Breaking a command into components using Natural Language Processing

Tags: nlp

I want to convert a variable assignment command into code. For example:
"create a variable alpha equal to the number 7" or
"define a new variable alpha and set it to 7", and either should convert into:

```
int alpha = 7;
```

How I plan on accomplishing this task is by looking for specific components in the string (e.g. variable name and variable value). Once I figure out that the variable name is "alpha" and the variable value is "7", I can construct the code seen above. But how would I go about finding the variable name and variable value through natural language processing? The user might add extra words or omit some words (or maybe even invert the order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very difficult problem. You can try some rules based on dependency syntax, that you can get e.g., from [spacy](https://spacy.io/), but the rules would probably cover only a small part of what people can actually say.

Researchers from CMU recently [published a dataset and announced a challenge](https://conala-corpus.github.io) for exactly this task. The challenge is running on [CodaLab](https://competitions.codalab.org/competitions/19175#results) and according to the leaderboard, it seems that all the submissions use neural networks trained on several thousand examples provided by the organizers.